# Isolated Margin

Tags: cryptocurrency, margin

[This question about leverage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/161398/is-betting-with-10-000x-leverage-on-stocks-just-crazy-fun-or-financial-folly) mentions "Isolated Margin".

A bit of googling leads me to think it is some crypto idea. The explanations I can find just states that the risk can be limited to some threshold you set - independent of how much you leverage.
As mentioned in several answers to the linked questions this is not possible in "classical" trading. I am also having a hard time understanding how it should be possible. At first I thought it was a scam description, but since several pages describes it, some thought must have been put into it - I just cannot figure out what.

Therefore - how is this *supposed* to be achieved with crypto?
Preferably, the answer would not involve a lot of crypto techno-babble, which is the reason I am asking here instead of on one of the crypto sub-sites here.

Comment: I suspect it involves brokers backing the currency and essentially being a part to the trade and not just broker. Which.... is a scam...

Answer (score -1):

I'm the person who asked the original question about leverage and mentioned isolated margin trading. **I did some research and I will now try to summarise what I found.**

---

### How Exchanges Try to Mitigate the Problem

- **Liquidation Engines:** Most reputable exchanges have sophisticated systems that try to execute rapid-fire liquidations the moment your account hits the liquidation price. They use techniques that break up your position to find the maximum buyers quickly.
- **Insurance Funds:** Some exchanges maintain an [insurance fund](https://support.coinex.com/hc/en-us/articles/900000296006-What-is-Margin-Insurance-Fund) to cover scenarios where a position experiences losses greater than the account's margin. These funds are usually built up using a small portion of fees from margin traders.
- **Risk Management Mechanisms:** Exchanges monitor market liquidity and adjust liquidation procedures during wild volatility. Sometimes they temporarily suspend margin trading in highly illiquid coins.

---

### My Experience with Isolated Margin Trading

I experimented with 100x Bitcoin trades on CoinEx, a Hong Kong-based exchange known for offering a wide range of altcoins and margin trading options. It was an interesting experience – sometimes I doubled my position, and sometimes I lost it all. **I DO NOT WANT TO ADVERTISE MARGIN TRADING IN THIS SECTION!**

[image: Crypto position closed with 100%+ profit]

- Type: Long Bitcoin (BTC) with 100x Leverage
- Position size: 0.106 BTC
- Average entry price: 44893.88 USDT
- Exit price: 45466.91 USDT
- Profit and loss (PNL): 117.57% or 55.95205813 USDT
- Position fees: 4.78912187 USDT

[image: Crypto position was liquidated with 102.5% losses]

- Type: Long Bitcoin (BTC) with 100x Leverage
- Position size: 0.025 BTC
- Average entry price: 22034.30 USDT
- Exit price: 21702.12 USDT
- Profit and loss (PNL): -102.5% or -11.29257875 USDT (-102.5% equals everything on my margin account)
- Position fees: 0.27542875 USDT

---

I tried to break it down as well as I could with some of my real-world examples. I haven't verified my identity on this exchange, so I highly doubt that I am even able to go into debt.

---

*Disclaimer: Isolated margin trading involves substantial risk. It amplifies both potential profits and losses. You could lose your entire margin for a specific position. Before participating, carefully assess your financial situation and risk tolerance.*

Comment: You are explaining how it is advertised as a service - this does not explain how it could possibly operate in a fair market. The presence of a theoretical, undefined 'insurance fund' looks like handwaving to avoid someone realizing that this financial product could be pure disaster for the broker [who theoretically is on the hook for downside], unless they had their thumb on the scale in some way.

Answer (score -3):

This is a term typically used on crypto exchanges that allow leverage trading (margin or futures).  It's not related to crypto inherently, just a way that some exchanges offer margin.

See "Cross vs Isolated Margin" here for a good description: https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/4844463246100-Margining-Liquidations-Multi-Collateral

> Isolated margin allows a trader to be in full control
> on how much leverage they are taking on a position and how much funds
> they want to have at risk at any given time. The Isolated Margin
> indicates the Initial Margin the system sets aside for the position
> opened for the specific contract, which is the Margin allocated to a
> position and the only funds at risk.   Initial Margin set aside for an
> Isolated position is excluded from Cross Risk margin calculations so
> Cross Liquidations do not impact Isolated Margin set aside, unless
> there is an account-wide liquidation then the isolated position will
> also get liquidated.
>
> Note: Funding rate payments in isolated positions
> are deducted from the general wallet balance rather than being
> included in the PnL which can cause liquidation in isolation.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of who absorbs the losses in the event that a trader's leveraged trade generates losses that exceed the "isolated margin"?  Right now the description sounds too good to be true (who wouldn't want unlimited upside with a fixed limit on downside)?  Also, you say that this concept is not inherently related to crypto.  Are there examples of conventional (i.e., non-crypto) brokerages offering "isolated margin"?  It seems many people around here have never heard the term; are there other synonymous terms that might be more widely known?

Comment: My comment that "it is not inherently related to crypto" isn't intended to suggest that it exists on non-crypto exchanges - I'm not aware that it does.  However, it's a concept found on crypto *exchanges*, it is not inherent to *cryptocurrencies* in any way.